# Intercepting jQuery ajax calls in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm using CouchDBs bundled $.couch API within an Angular application.  I'd like to intercept ALL ajax requests, whether from Angular's $http service or jQuery's $.ajax (which is what $.couch uses).  I have an interceptor set up in angular as follows:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$location', '$q',  function($location, $q) {
      return {
          'request': function(request) {
              return request;
          },
          'responseError': function(response) {
              if (response.status === 401) {
                console.log("UH OH")
              }
              // otherwise, default behaviour
              return $q.reject(response);
          }
      };
  }]);
```

and what I've noticed is that requests and response errors from the $http angular service are caught, but the $.ajax calls and errors are not.  So my question is, what's the proper way for me to intercept all ajax requests in my app from in and out of angular?  Ideally I'd like to have one handler for both.

Answer (score 0):

don't have a true answer, but surely interceptors are an array of property *specific* of angular's $httpProvider object. None similar is present in jquery. No way that code of yours could know something about $.ajax calls. I don't know, maybe you could wrap jquery ajax in a promise, re-creating something like interceptors.

in this post is described *how interceptors are made under the hood* in angular. This could be an hint for you.
[what are interceptors](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/03/angular-http-interceptors-source/)

[more info](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, we ended up moving away from the jquery couch to a completely angular $http implementation, so now all the ajax calls are intercepted.

Comment: the problem is when you use a third party library, like svgxuse :)

Comment: i think that's not a better way than passing everiything througth angular facilities. Another cleaner way would be make a factory for rest call who sets the appropriate header once for all and generate services from there for every call, passing external lib rest call to those services.